# Pysimplegui index

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to ask someting about the pysimplegui, I tried to put an index under the elif function of table list, the system already read the first row of table when I tried to add quantity but the second row also read the function of first row, I wanted to add another value of 2nd row and other rows not to read the value of the first row after I click, can you help me? This is my code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMaS2.jpg)

Comment: `['-TABLE-'][1]` means the second item in a list which with only one item, then you will get exception `IndexError: list index out of range`. Not sure what your question is just by your simple description, and post your code in text if not too long and possible.

Comment: @JasonYang i also want to add quantity in 2nd list of table but the system didn't read it, just the value of first row. How to code that thing, if i wanted to read the 2nd row?

Comment: @JasonYang can i ask for your help with my project? I really don't know what to do next

Comment: Try to post an issue in https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues, remember to fill the issue form step by step, or you will be rejected, code in text form, better with image, or best with GIF/movie if required, to descript your question there. Tell the truth, I am not sure what question you are here by your above description.

Comment: If you pip installed PySimpleGUI, then you can also type `psgissue` from the command line and you will be shown a GUI to help post a GitHub issue.